# Which scenario gives you more chances to win, assuming that the results of each match are independent?

Tags: probability, recreational-mathematics, independence

You are to play three matches, and you have to win two consecutive matches our of those three. There are two scenarios in which you can play:

- against a champion, against a friend, then against a champion
- against a friend, against a champion, then against a friend.

If the results of each match are independent, which scenario gives you better chances of winning two consecutive matches?

Comment: Intuition suggests that it's better to go $CFC$ since you absolutely must win the middle game.  Just compute both cases to confirm.

Comment: @lulu I presume you mean $FCF$, since it'd make sense for you to be more likely to win with a champ.

Comment: Are you more likely to win against a friend or a champion?

Comment: @DonThousand:no, lulu is right.  You are not trying to win the maximum number of games, you are trying to win two in a row.  It is counterintuitive, which is why it is a good puzzle.

Comment: @DonThousand  Oh, I read the question as saying you are playing $\textit {against}$ a champion or a friend.  And I assumed that you have a greater chance of beating your friend.

Comment: @lulu:  in this problem I read "play with" as a synonym for "play against".

Comment: @RossMillikan  Yes, that's how I read it as well.

Comment: My take is the following. Let $f$ denote the probability to win with a friend. Let $c$ denote the probability to win with a champion. There are two cases in which you can win. You win the first two matches. Or you loose the first one and then you win the next two matches. When you play CFC the probability of winning is: $cf + (1-c)fc$. When you play FCF the probability of winning is: $fc + (1-f)cf$. Since $1-f > 1-c$, FCF gives you better chances. Is that correct?

Comment: @elelel  As you can see from the comments, people are unclear as to the rules.  RossMillikan and I are reading the problem as saying you are playing $\textit {against}$ a champ or a friend, so using your notation you'd have $f>c$.  Perhaps you meant something else, but in either case you should clarify.

Comment: @lulu, I mean that you play _against_ a champion or a friend. So we have $f > c$, where $f$ means the probability of winning against a friend and $c$ means the probability of winning against a champion. So the probability of winning in CFC is: $cf + (1-c)fc$. The probability of winning in FCF is: $fc + (1-f)cf$. Since $f>c$, we have $1-c > 1-f$ (I made a mistake in my previous post). So CFC gives you better chances. Correct?

Comment: Yes.  With that reading $CFC$ is better, for the reason you give.  Again, I think that is intuitive since it is essential that you win the second game.